# How can I run tests against all browsers in karma.conf.js, without making all browsers the default, or having to list them all on the command line?

Tags: karma-runner

I have a `karma.conf.js` that has defines browsers and a lot of custom launchers for testing on Browser Stack:

```
browsers: ["Chrome", "Firefox"],
customLaunchers: {
  IE11: {
    base: "BrowserStack",
    browser: "IE",
    browser_version: "11",
    os: "Windows",
    os_version: "10",
  },
  IE10: {
    base: "BrowserStack",
    browser: "IE",
    browser_version: "10",
    os: "Windows",
    os_version: "8",
  },
  // ...
}
```

Most of the time I want to run only against Chrome and Firefox, but once in a while I want to have the tests run against all browsers known to the configuration.

I know I could put all keys of `customLaunchers` in `browsers` but that's not a great option because it would mean that most of the time I'd have to pass `--browsers` to limit the run to Chrome and Firefox.

I know I could list all the browsers on the command line but that's cumbersome because the list has 11 items in it and would grow even longer over time.

So is there a way to tell Karma "run against all the launchers known to you from `karma.conf.js`"? I've checked the documentation, searched issues and SO and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option that I know of. However, the `karma.conf.js` file can be modified to accept a fake browser name like `all` that can be used as a signal that custom code in `karma.conf.js` should set the configuration to use all browsers known to the configuration file:

```
module.exports = function configure(config) {
  "use strict";
  var options = {
    basePath: "",
    // ...
    browsers: ["Chrome", "Firefox"],
    customLaunchers: {
      IE11: // ...
      IE10: // ...,
      // ...
    }
  };

  // If the user passed `--browsers all`, then we grab the list
  // from the `options` object and modify `config.browsers`.
  var browsers = config.browsers;
  if (browsers.length === 1 && browsers[0] === "all") {
    var newList = options.browsers.concat(Object.keys(options.customLaunchers));

    browsers.splice.apply(browsers, [0, browsers.length].concat(newList));
  }

  config.set(options);
}
```

The `options` object contains the configuration for your project. When the user passes `--browsers all` on the command line, the value of `config.browsers` is **modified in place** to list all browsers. Note that it has to be modified in place. Replacing the value with a new array won't work, probably because Karma stores a reference before `karma.conf.js` is run and uses that reference from then on. Also, modifying the value of `options.browsers` has no effect, because `config.browsers` has priority. (Otherwise, `--browsers [...]` would not override what is in the configuration passed through `karma.conf.js`.)